# Testing user experience from multiple countries

Tags: facebook, internationalization

I'm working on an app that displays slightly different behavior based on the country that the user is in. I'm using the signed_request['user']['country'] parameter (which from my research appears to be set by a geographic lookup), and I'd like to find a way to simulate a visitor hitting my app from a different country.

Things I've tried:

- Looking for special settings for test users
- Changing locale settings
  in facebook

Is there anything that can help me short of proxying my access to Facebook through a foreign http proxy?

Comment: This question may be slightly off-topic for Stackoverflow as many here tend to lean towards the code rather than the management.  As an alternative, you can ask the same question on http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ and probably get more response from it there.